# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart

My code:

```
          var postdata = {
            "id": "6DFA5E06-3B1C-4507-B831-2D84B4137011", 
            "subject": "Test", 
            "message": "Test", 
            "recipients": ["6CA682DD-BC13-40FB-BB31-1971553DE8F6", "763661B9-0378-4F81-8A98-6B5962752D4A"]
          },
          res = await http.post(
              Uri.parse(AuthService().baseUrl + uri),
              body: postdata, 
              headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + value["token"],
              },
          );
```

Got this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'List'

Comment: I got that error on my postdata. But if I remove the recipients in my postdata. The code will successfully execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encode your data using dart built-in functions for JSON in the `dart:convert` package. Dart uses Map<String, dynamic> in place of JSON.

Import `dart:convert` into your program and try this:

```
    var postdata = {
        "id": "6DFA5E06-3B1C-4507-B831-2D84B4137011", 
        "subject": "Test", 
        "message": "Test", 
        "recipients": ["6CA682DD-BC13-40FB-BB31-1971553DE8F6", "763661B9-0378-4F81-8A98-6B5962752D4A"]
    },
    res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(AuthService().baseUrl + uri),
        body: jsonEncode(postdata), 
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + value["token"],
        },
    );
```

Here is the link to the Flutter Cookbook explaining this:

[Flutter - Send data to the internet](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data)